# make a transparent part of an image unclickable

Tags: android

I use Android studio and I have this image with a transparent background. Whenever i click on it it'll bring me to another Activity. But even when I click on the transparent part of the image it'll bring me to the other Activity.
Is it possible to make the nontransparent part clickable (or touchable) and the transparent part unclickable?

Comment: Please show image and/or XML of what you are referring to. You have a custom background for your button?

Comment: Did you figure this out and have an answer to post? It's ok to post your own answer if the others don't help you enough that you want to accept them, but it's good to accept an answer so other people with the same problem find it

Comment: Yeah I usually accept the answer, seems like I forgot it here. The answer you included did work well. ty :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible but it becomes much more difficult  than just adding an OnClickListener.

The trick is to use a Touch listener instead of click and on either a DOWN or UP event take the position and then either use some simple maths to work out whether it was a transparent area (if the design is a simple one) or, do some more complicated stuff to work out your pixel values at the centre.

```
 new View.OnTouchListener() {
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         If (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             final int x = (int) event.getX();
             final int y = (int) event.getY();

             //now map the coords we got to the
             //bitmap (because of scaling) 
             ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
             Bitmap bitmap =((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
             int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

             //now check alpha for transparency 
             int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
             If (alpha != 0) {
                  //do whatever you would have done for your click event here
             } 
         }
         return true; //we've handled the event
     }
 }
```